# MediaPlayer inside an adapter playing the wrong track

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I'm fairly new to Android development, and I added a MediaPlayer in a list of items so that the pronunciation is played for each word listed.

However, the wrong track is playing, I can't figure out how to link the right track to each item in the list view.
The ID changes when I'm scrolling for example as I can see in logs, so I think there's something I misunderstood.
What I fail to understand is why it works for the ImageView for example, but not for the audio file.

```
public class WordsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Words>{

    private int colorview;
    private View listItemView;
    private Words currentWords;

    public WordsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Words> words, int color){

        super(context, 0, words);
        colorview = color;

        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_view_black, parent, false);
        }

        currentWords = getItem(position);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageicon);
        if(currentWords.hasImage()) {
            image.setImageResource((currentWords.getImageID()));
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_default);
        defaultTextView.setText(currentWords.getDefaultWord());

        TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_miwok);
        miwokTextView.setText(currentWords.getMiwokWord());

        View linearWords = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_words);
        linearWords.setBackgroundResource(colorview);



        Button ButtonPlay = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        ButtonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), currentWords.getAudioFile());
                Log.v("Audio id : ", player.getTrackInfo().toString());
                player.start();
            }
        });
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The variable currentWords needs to be declared inside the method and set to final.

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

[...]

final Words currentWords = getItem(position);

[...]

}